# Vue - why can't I display the result of my axios get request in vuex?

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

I am working with Laravel,  vue, vuex and axios

I am trying to get data from database and display in my component

Here's my `lists.vue` file

```
    <specialist v-for="doctor in DoctorsPerDayData" :key="doctor.id">

        <template slot="speciality">
            <a class=" button specialist" @click="clicked(doctor)">
                <strong>
                    {{ doctor.speciality}}
                </strong>
            </a>
        </template>
        <template slot="doctor">{{ doctor.name}}</template>

    </specialist>
```

I am testing the commented code but still get the same result

```
computed: {
//       ...mapGetters([
//                'DoctorsPerDayData'
//            ]),
//            DoctorsPerDayData (){
//               return this.$store.state.DoctorsPerDay
//            }
     DoctorsPerDayData : {
           get(){
               return this.$store.state.DoctorsPerDay
           }
     }

        methods:{
        ...mapActions([
            'UpdateDoctorsPerDay'
        ]),
    },
    mounted() {
        this.UpdateDoctorsPerDay();
    }
```

here's my `store.js` file

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
state:{
    DoctorsPerDay: null,
},
getters:{
    DoctorsPerDayData: state => {
        return state.DoctorsPerDay
    }
},
mutations:{
    UpdateDoctorsPerDay(state , DoctorsPerDay ){
        state.DoctorsPerDay = DoctorsPerDay;
    }
},
actions:{
    UpdateDoctorsPerDay: ({commit})=>{
        axios.get('/get/Doctors/date')
            .then((response) => {
                commit('UpdateDoctorsPerDay', response.data)
            })
    },
}
});
```

On the other side my vuex dev tool shows `DoctorsPerDay` have data

[image]

I don't get any error :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for test make a new laravel project and do the specefic example with vue and vuex , I see it's work !

As a result I just make new laravel project and move my files in there with precisely step by step,

and it's work perfectly :| ;)

sorry my engilish is not good enough ;)

good Luck ...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you wrote this chunk of code inside the `computed` key.

```
1 //    ...mapGetters([
2 //        'DoctorsPerDayData'
3 //     ]),
4 //    DoctorsPerDayData (){
5 //        return this.$store.state.DoctorsPerDay
6 //    }
7       DoctorsPerDayData : {
8           get(){
9               return this.$store.state.DoctorsPerDay
10          }
11      }
```

### Posible solution 1

For block in line `1-3` I've previously used `mapGetters` as a way to convert upper camel case into camel case like this.

```
...mapGetters({
    doctorsPerDayData: 'DoctorsPerDayData'
}),
```

After this you may use `doctorsPerDayData` in your `<template>...html</template>` like this `<specialist v-for="doctor in doctorsPerDayData" :key="doctor.id">`

### Posible solution 2

Then I would say in block line `7-11` it should be `return this.$store.getters.DoctorsPerDay` note the difference of `getters` instead of `state`.

Comment: tested 2 solutions , same result  :(

Comment: Could you share how your `specialist.vue` looks like?